# Update query using Firestore in react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I Want to preform and update query using Firestore. i know how to work with it but not completely.

I have a flatlist which presenting data and an a text with touchable opacity onPress that will create a new Firestore collection and set the flatList to Firestore.

What is my goal? :
1.I want to check if there is any data in the collection, if there is a data, i want to update it without overwrite the previous data depending on the current user ID.

My current query code:

```
   const handleFBAll = () => {
      // const businessUser = snapshot.docs[0].data();
      const businessIde = currentBusinessUid;
      console.log("ID : ", businessIde);
      firebase.firestore().collection("users").doc(businessIde).collection("pending-sales").doc(currentUser.uid).set({servicesMaxMin})
    }
```

now i want to update the doc of the currentUser with additional data if there is one

Suggetions?

Comment: use `update` instead of `set`

Comment: Thats it?
no need to preform checks and etc?

Comment: thats correct, just provide it the data you want updated, it will merge with the existing data. if any props you provide already exist, they will be overwritten.

Comment: Okay, im trying it right now

Comment: Actually i have an error, if i will change it to update before i have an existing document it will get me: "FirebaseError: No document to update"
My goal is at first create a document with data, and then in later stages to preform an update if necessery

Comment: In that case, first do a `get` on your doc ref and see if it `exists`, if it doesn't use `set` otherwise use `udpate`.

Comment: you can also call `set` with `merge` prop  set to true and that will save you doing the check

Comment: Im not familiar with the merge prop so will try the first way u suggested

Comment: can you help me in chat? i cant figure out\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223513/discussion-between-nishkaush-and-osher-revach).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` prop with `set` and that should allow you to simplify the code a little like so:

```js
db.collection('dogs').doc('my-id').set({
  "owner": "james"
},{merge:true})
```

this will add `owner` prop if it doesn't exist or will overwrite it.